# Are there differences when creating a tensor with an array of boxed types (eg, Integer) vs an array of primitives in tensorflow

Tags: java, tensorflow

I am trying to get a definitive answer whether there are any differences between two tensors created from `Tensor.create(new int[3])` and `Tensor.create(new Integer[3])`, respectively. They have exactly the same data type (INT32) and shape ([3]). I think they are identical. However, the `setValue` call inside the `Tensor` class is a native call and I can't really be sure if there is any difference inside native code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like everything get resolved as a primitive type in [this method](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/96afaa08b282a32870a9ccd20bce42110e4a0adb/tensorflow/java/src/main/native/tensor_jni.cc#L119), so I guess that JNI do some kind of primitive unboxing? I'm not too sure how that works neither.

But FYI, all those tensor creators using reflection magic have been removed in the next generation of TensorFlow Java, as they are not performant. You might want to take a look [at this repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/java) for more details.